# Disable onClicklistener When Internet is not availaible

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, android-adapter

I'm using an adapter class to populate my Fragment with Blogpost and Like Button. But when device is offlline and when User presses like button then app crashes.
So I'm looking forward to disable the click function when Device is offline and only enable when device is online.

So How can I apply button to clickable(false); when device is offline.

Here is my BlogRecycleadapter class code

```
package com.nepalpolice.cdp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FieldValue;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

import static com.nepalpolice.cdp.webfaq.isNetworkStatusAvialable;

public class BlogRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BlogRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public List<BlogPost> blog_list;
    public Context context;
    private Button mbutton;

    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    public BlogRecyclerAdapter(List<BlogPost> blog_list){

        this.blog_list = blog_list;

    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.blog_list_item, parent, false);
        context = parent.getContext();
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mbutton = (Button)  view.findViewById(R.id.blog_like_btn);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

        final String blogPostId = blog_list.get(position).BlogPostId;
        final String currentUserId = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        String desc_data = blog_list.get(position).getDesc();
        holder.setDescText(desc_data);

        String image_url = blog_list.get(position).getImage_url();
        holder.setBlogImage(image_url);

        String user_id = blog_list.get(position).getUser_id();
        //User Data will be retrieved here...
        firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

                if(task.isSuccessful()){

                    String userName = task.getResult().getString("name");
                    String userImage = task.getResult().getString("image");

                    holder.setUserData(userName, userImage);


                } else {

                    //Firebase Exception

                }

            }
        });


        long millisecond = blog_list.get(position).getTimestamp().getTime();
        String dateString = DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yyyy", new Date(millisecond)).toString();
        holder.setTime(dateString);

        //Get Likes Count
        firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostId + "/Likes").addSnapshotListener(((Main2Activity) context),new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                if (!documentSnapshots.isEmpty()){

int count = documentSnapshots.size();
holder.updateLikesCount(count);

                }else{
holder.updateLikesCount(0);

                }

            }
        });



        //Get Likes

        firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostId + "/Likes").document(currentUserId).addSnapshotListener(((Main2Activity) context),new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                if (documentSnapshot.exists()){

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        holder.blogLikeBtn.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.mipmap.action_like_accent));
                    }
                    else {
                        holder.blogLikeBtn.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.action_like_accent));
                    }
                } else {

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        holder.blogLikeBtn.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.mipmap.action_like_gray));
                    }else{
                        holder.blogLikeBtn.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.action_like_gray));
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        //like Feature

        holder.blogLikeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostId + "/Likes").document(currentUserId).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if (!task.getResult().exists()){

                            Map<String, Object> likesMap = new HashMap<>();
                            likesMap.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());


                            firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostId + "/Likes").document(currentUserId).set(likesMap);

                        } else {
                            firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostId + "/Likes").document(currentUserId).delete();

                        }

                    }
                });



            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return blog_list.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private View mView;

        private TextView descView;
        private ImageView blogImageView;
        private TextView blogDate;

        private TextView blogUserName;
        private CircleImageView blogUserImage;
        private ImageView blogLikeBtn;
        private  TextView blogLikeCount;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;



        }

        public void setDescText(String descText){

            descView = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_desc);
            descView.setText(descText);

            blogLikeBtn = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_like_btn);
        }

        public void setBlogImage(String downloadUri){

            blogImageView = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_image);
            RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
            requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.image_placeholder);
            Glide.with(context).applyDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions).load(downloadUri).into(blogImageView);

        }

        public void setTime(String date) {

            blogDate = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_date);
            blogDate.setText(date);

        }

        public void setUserData(String name, String image){

            blogUserImage = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_user_image);
            blogUserName = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_user_name);

            blogUserName.setText(name);

            RequestOptions placeholderOption = new RequestOptions();
            placeholderOption.placeholder(R.drawable.profile_placeholder);

            Glide.with(context).applyDefaultRequestOptions(placeholderOption).load(image).into(blogUserImage);

        }

public void  updateLikesCount (int count){

            blogLikeCount = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_like_count);
            blogLikeCount.setText(count + "Likes");
}

    }
```

Here is the image file of error report

[image]

I used

```
 mimageview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.blog_like_btn);
```

and

```
if (!isNetworkStatusAvialable(mimageview.getContext())){
mimageview.setClickable(false);
}
```

But it still throws me an error and didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Your question could be better and get more answers if you distilled your code down to the bare minimum.  That way, the developers attempting to help you won't have to understand all of your code.

Comment: @RandyStegbauer, I have updated my question with solution I tried...I hope it'll be any help to understand what I' want to implement here.

Comment: That's better, but could still be better.  The code that you have included is way too long.  Most developers won't spend the time to read and *understand* what you have asked.  Please read [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Heres code that would check whether the user has an internet connection.

```
 ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
      = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if(!(activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected())){
 //user does not have an internet connection
 //put code here that diables the button 
} else {
//user does have an internet connection
//put code here that enables the button
 }
```

Add this code to when you bind the data to the view and disable the button if you dont have a connection.

Based on your code it would look something like this:

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
      = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if(!(activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected())){
 //user does not have an internet connection
 //heres code that diables the button 
 holder.blogLikeBtn.clickable(false);
}
//put the rest of your method code here
}
```

Although this is one way to solve your problem, a better way would be to add this code to the onClick event of the button and then check if the user has a connection and if he does not then show him a dialog explaining to him that he needs an internet connection and then exiting.

These are two approaches to solving your problem.

Note: Make sure you add this permission to your manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />` otherwise you will get a Exception when using the above code.

Comment: it doesn't solve the problem, instead it throws error in getSystemService and isConnected and ctiveNetworkInfo. Please see the image above that I have attached in question.

Comment: @RishiramRanabhat you have to put the code inside a method. In the onBindViewHolder method sounds like a good place

Comment: @RishiramRanabhat and when you bind the data to the view, if you dont have a connection then disable the button

Comment: Even if I put the code inside onBindViewHolder.....still I'm getting error of can't resolve getSystemservice method?? How do I solve this??

Comment: @RishiramRanabhat that means you have to import the class.

Comment: and How should I import class and which class whould I import?? can you please help me to solve this?

Comment: When you hover over the error, click the light bulb and click import class

Comment: Please check the image https://ibb.co/dmDO0S Here I"m not getting any import class method.

Comment: Ah, I understand the problem, you are not in an activity or class that is a context

Comment: @RishiramRanabhat you have to call the getSystemService mthods from a context object

Answer (score 1):

Create a class.

```
public class InternetStatus {

    private static InternetStatus instance = new InternetStatus();
    static Context context;
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
    NetworkInfo wifiInfo, mobileInfo;
    boolean connected = false;

    public static InternetStatus getInstance(Context ctx) {
        context = ctx.getApplicationContext();
        return instance;
    }

    public boolean isOnline() {
        try {
            connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            connected = networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() &&
                    networkInfo.isConnected();
            return connected;


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("CheckConnectivity Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            Log.v("connectivity", e.toString());
        }
        return connected;
    }


}
```

Use it like so... change this....

```
if (InternetStatus.getInstance(context.isOnline()) {
    Log.i(TAG, "User is online");
} else {
    Log.e(TAG, "User does not have an internet connection");
}
```

Also, you shouldn't disable a button before the user has the ability to press it. You should allow the user to press the button, then check if there is a connection. If not, show a snackbar or toast or dialogbox.

Comment: Good point at the end, just disabling the button would not explain to the user what is wrong, but showing a dialog when the user clicks the button would make things clearer

Comment: I'm getting error on cannot resolve getApplicationContext() method. How do I solve it?

Comment: its the Context of your app. if you created another class, getApplicationContext should be able to be picked up. Try cleaning the project or/and rebuilding.

Comment: its also a very good idea to understand the code before you copy and paste an answer....

Comment: @DroiDev,  After cleaning or rebuilding ....still I'm getting same error.

Comment: getApplicationContext() is getting... i bet you wouldnt be able to get this... the CONTEXT of the application. If arleady created the Context context... use that. see above.